# Clip that plays fine in WMP is cut off in Sony Vegas

Tags: video, video-editor, vegas-pro, h.264, video-game

I imported a screen recording into Sony Vegas. When I play the original clip with Windows Media Player, it looks the way I expect it, with the whole screen visible. But when I play the clip in Vegas, it's zoomed in on the left side and the right side is just CUT out. Trying to change the crop or resize doesn't have any effect, everything on the rest of the screen is just gone, it's not there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeG1j.jpg

1. In the first image, you can see the original clip and everything is visible.
2. In the second image, you can see the clip inside of Vegas and how it's cut off.
3. In the third image, you can see that after i crop/pan it doesn't matter the clip is just cut off inside of Vegas.

How can I import the full screen?

Comment: Answered at reddit. Reposting answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Vegas issue. The recording application has registered the video resolution as `1024x768` in the MP4 global header (`../stsd/avc1`) but the full 1080p stream is captured and stored.

Vegas is using the header metadata to crop the video stream at the stage of loading the file. So, any Vegas functions/plugins downstream to this stage don't, know of, or have access to the full image data.

However, the full resolution is correctly stored in the metadata (SPS) of the video stream itself. So remuxing the file with ffmpeg will resolve the issue as ffmpeg constructs a new global header, based on reading the stream metadata.

```
ffmpeg -i recorded.mp4 -c copy fixed.mp4
```

Get a FFmpeg Windows binary from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: wow, i cannot explain with words how grateful i am!

you are really clever my man! much love. i have no idea what any of those words mean but it worked, thank you once again <3